# Prevent user entered data from clearing on new window load

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a small desktop app that loads numerous windows and pages into a main screen into a grid on a button click. The relevant page loads into the grid and users then enter data in text boxes, selected radio questions and so on. They can then copy the data entered and paste it into where they need to paste it. Simple macro type desktop app.

My main issue is when the users click from one loaded window and goes to another macro that then deletes all previously entered data. So if the user then goes back to a previous macro it reloads as new.

Each window/macro has a reset button and I would ultimately like to have all data saved until that is used or app is closed.

Thanks for any help!

Update: added code below. Simple app that has a main window/landing page and a grid. On button click grid loads a page (page2 or page3) dependent on which button is clicked. If A user enters text in text boxes, goes to a different page by clicking the other button and then goes to page with said button previously entered data is gone.

code breakdown:

main screen xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="test.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:test"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="1001">

    <Grid x:Name="loadgrid" Height="500" Background="White" Margin="423,110,61,110">
        <Button Content="Button" Margin="-298,29,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="113" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Margin="-298,97,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="113" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

main screen CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            loadgrid.Children.Add(new test.BlankPage1());
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            loadgrid.Children.Add(new test.page3());
        }
    }
}
```

page1 xaml

```
<Page x:Name="page2"
    x:Class="test.BlankPage1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:test"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="#FFF57A7A" Width="400" Height="400">

    <Grid>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,53,0,0" Text="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" AllowFocusWhenDisabled="True"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,116,0,0" Text="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,168,0,0" Text="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

page1 cs

```
namespace test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class BlankPage1 : Page
    {
        public BlankPage1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

page3 xaml

```
<Page x:Name="page1"
    x:Class="test.page3"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:test"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="#FF5C838F" Width="400" Height="400">

    <Grid>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="123,105,0,0" Text="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="173"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="123,168,0,0" Text="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="173"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="123,227,0,0" Text="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="173"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

page3 cs

```
namespace test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class page3 : Page
    {
        public page3()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using MVVM, even though it is a very small and simple macro type app. If you want to solve your issue without fixing the architecture, you'll get much better results if you post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I have no idea what your app does, or how it does it.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I added a simple app breakdown into the original in hopes that helps.

Comment: Please take a look at how the formatting is now done in your question. Are you saying that when you create a new instance of `test.page3`, you want it to have the same state that some previous instance had? I'd recommend writing viewmodels. [Here's a basic MVVM tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnshews_blog/2015/09/09/a-minimal-mvvm-uwp-app/) for UWP. That design isn't particularly applicable to to your problem, but it illustrates how to have your *data* in a viewmodel, and which can be re-displayed in any instance of an appropriate view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ed_Plunkett said, if you want to save the state of user input, you can use MVVM. Simply put, the user's input is saved to a variable for the next page load.

But as far as your current code is concerned, `Page` is best to use Frame for navigation. If you need to add some controls directly to the Page, you can create a `UserControl`.

Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol) about `UserControl`.

Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/navigation-basics) about `Navigation`.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

hi you can enable the page cache mode at the start of the page it store the entire page cache data check boxes data n all.
`this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;`